# Set Execution Context Selector in Chrome via console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working with JavaScript and need to refresh the browser a lot.
The [Execution Context Selector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#execution-context) always jumps back to "top".

Is there a line of code that automatically sets the desired file.

Just to be sure, here is a picture of the
[Execution Context Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCwH.png)

Sorry, it's not possible for me to embed yet.
Longtime lurker, this is the first time I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `debugger;` statement in your code devtools will break on this line of code and execution context will be automatically set.

Comment: Thank you @pranay-kumar, this will save me a lot of clicking!!

Comment: @Pranay Kumar any solution for source code on Console tab instead of source code on file?