# How to change order of javascript context in console window in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I am working on a tool that has its own debugger. I can select it from the drop-down option in the javascript context in the Chrome console window as shown in the following image.

[image]

So, every time I refresh the chrome page, this option resets to "top". For every tiniest change, I have to manually select the debugger from the drop-down option.

Is there any way to change the order in the dropdown menu or if I can save my chrome console setting so that my debugger will be on top instead of the "top" option?

I tried to search any shortcuts of moving up-down in the dropdown menu but found nothing. Any suggestion to minimize my manual work would be highly helpful.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277214/set-execution-context-selector-in-chrome-via-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277214/set-execution-context-selector-in-chrome-via-console)